# How to show that $\mid{ \frac{1+\lambda(\cos q_{m}\Delta y+ \cos k_{m}\Delta x -2)}{1-\lambda(\cos q_{m}\Delta y +\cos k_{m}\Delta x -2)}\mid} \leq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to show the stability of the Crank-Nicholson schema for the heat equation in 2 spatial dimensions, using the Von Neumann's stability analysis. After doing the algebra I was left with showing that $\mid{ \frac{1+\lambda(\cos q_{m}\Delta y+ \cos k_{m}\Delta x -2)}{1-\lambda(\cos q_{m}\Delta y +\cos k_{m}\Delta x -2)}\mid} \leq 1$. Note that $\lambda>0$.

**My reasoning.**
Consider the function $f(x, y)= \cos k_{m}\Delta x+\sin q_{m}\Delta y$, its critical points are $(0,0)$ and $(\pi, \pi)$. Note that $(0, 0)$ minimizes the denominator. Evaluating the numerator at $(0,0)$ the expression reduces to $1\leq 1$ and evaluating at $(\pi, \pi)$ it simplifies to $\mid 1- 4\lambda\mid \leq 1$.

I was wondering if you could provide some feedback on this. Is there a more rigorous way to go about it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is exactly what you should do. However, perhaps it is easier to write the problem as $$\phi(z) = \bigg \lvert \frac{1 + z}{1 - z} \bigg \rvert, \quad z = \lambda (\cos q_{m} \Delta y + \cos k_{m} \Delta x - 2)$$ Then note that when $z > 0, \phi(z) > 1$ (with a pole at $z = 1$) and when $z \le 0, \phi(z) \le 1$. Therefore, it suffices to determine whether $z$ can ever be positive which, as $\lambda > 0$, would require $$\cos q_{m} \Delta y + \cos k_{m} \Delta x > 2$$